# Merging Drop down from two Tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I like to know how to merge two table attributes and summarize them in a single drop down.

I tried to create a method in the create form helper which i referenced the attributes of the table.

---

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :Destinations %>
    <%= form.collection_select(:destination_id, Destination.all, :id, destname_with_klm(@createform.destination), {}, { :multiple => false } ) %>
  </div>
```

---

createforms_helper.rb

```rb
module CreateformsHelper

  def destname_with_klm(f)
    "#{f.Destination_name}.#{f.Destination_kilometre}"
end
end
```

```sh
NoMethodError in Createforms#new
Showing **/app/views/createforms/_form.html.erb where line #34 raised:

undefined method `Destination_name' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Make sure the object you are passing has Destination_name attribute.

Comment: Try lower case of ur  destination_name

Comment: I tried it all its the same

Answer (score 0):

the error you are getting `undefined method "Destination_name" for nil:NilClass` is because the parameter (`f`) you pass is nil

However, I think you can update the model and make the code bit cleaner. (I had a look at the formatted suggested edit and gather this info)

```
#app/models/destination.rb

class Destination < ActiveRecord::Base
   #other code 
   def destination_name_with_kms
     # I believe the attribute names should be lowercase 
     "#{Destination_name}.#{Destination_kilometre}"
   end
end

#in your view
<%= form.collection_select(:destination_id, Destination.all, :id, destination_name_with_kms, {}, { :multiple => false } ) %>
```

If you want to go one step further, I would recommend to use a decorator gem like 
[Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper), and move all the UI formatting to a decorator.

Comment: Thanks. 

But i still got an error. 

NameError in Createforms#new
Showing /*app/views/createforms/_form.html.erb where line #34 raised:

uninitialized constant CreateformsHelper::Destination_name
Extracted source (around line #4):
              def destname_with_klm
    "#{Destination_name}. #{Destination_kilometre}"
end
end

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/createforms/new.html.erb

---------------------------
In your above solution, is there a column missing when referencing destination_name_with_kms as in should it be :destination_name_with_kms
.tried both.